# Vim automatically clear the command line

Tags: vim, vimrc

When using vim I like to keep my command line (the line where messages, warnings and errors are printed) empty, so after saving a file I usually issue a `<C-l>` to redraw the screen and clear it.

Is there a way to automate this process, so that after n seconds of something being printed in the command line, an automatic `<C-l>` is executed?

Comment: You can clear the console after saving a file using the `BufWritePost` event: `:autocmd BufWritePost <buffer> ...`

Comment: Can I put a timer on that action, so for ex clear the console 5 seconds after saving?

Comment: I believe this is not an easy task, have a look at [this](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/11667/).

Answer (score 5):

The following autocommands may do what you want

```
" Clear cmd line message
function! s:empty_message(timer)
  if mode() ==# 'n'
    echon ''
  endif
endfunction

augroup cmd_msg_cls
    autocmd!
    autocmd CmdlineLeave :  call timer_start(5000, funcref('s:empty_message'))
augroup END
```

It will clear the commandline output 5 seconds after `CmdlineLeave` event is fired. It sort of works as you want. You may tweak the time as you wish.

Comment: so by just running `echon ''`, the command-line screen will be cleared?

Comment: Yes, because you printed an empty message in the statusline.

Comment: i saw it, it works. but not always, sometimes doesnt clear the cmd

Comment: @alexzander If vim is busy doing something, the time to to the callback function may not be exactly 5 seconds.

Comment: im not using your autogroup. im clearing the cmd when a custom defined function is called. that function is called when i press control+S to save the file.

Answer (score 1):

Adding to @jdhao answer, you can use the `CursorHold` event instead which uses the value of `updatetime` as a timeout and will trigger whenever no key is pressed.

For example:

```
    autocmd CursorHold * echon ''
```